# Argument list too long when removing files in trash

Tags: bash, delete, trash

I have about 1,000,000 png images to remove from my trash. I tried:

1. `rm -rf /home/ahmed/.local/share/Trash/*`
2. `find . -name '*' | xargs rm -v`

I got the following

```
bash: /usr/bin/find: Argument list too long
```

Comment: Are you sure `find . -name '*' ` gave you that error? With the asterisk quoted?

Comment: Have you tried `gvfs-trash --empty` ?

Answer (score 5):

`ARG_MAX` is being triggered in the process of listing/removal.

You can:

- Let `find` handle the removal, it inherently handles `ARG_MAX`:

  ```
  find /home/ahmed/.local/share/Trash/ -type f -iname '*.png' -delete
  ```
- Leverage a `for` construct, this is slow BTW:

  ```
  for f in /home/ahmed/.local/share/Trash/*.[Pp][Nn][Gg]; do 
      [[ -f $f ]] && rm "$f"
  done
  ```

Answer (score 1):

The shell expands the wildcard `*` to all filenames, which overflows the maximum command line length. Although in your second example, this cannot happen, because the asterisk is in quotes `'*'`.

---

To remove the whole directory, you may also remove the directory itself

```
rm -rf /home/ahmed/.local/share/Trash
```

Note the missing wildcard at the end.

---

Another approach to avoid this kind of error with `find`, could be to use `-type f`. This option selects all regular files, e.g.

```
find . -type f | xargs rm -v
```

With 1,000,000 files though, I would avoid option `-v`.